# How to properly escape Regular Expression pattern in XSD schema?

Tags: regex, xml, date, xsd, escaping

I need to fulfill a requirement to only accept values in the form of MM/DD/YYYY.

From what I've read on: https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-2/#nt-dateRep
Using

```
<xs:simpleType name="DATE">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:date"/>
    </xs:simpleType>
```

Is not going to work as its regex apparently is not supporting this format.

I have found and adjusted this format:

```
^(?:(?:(?:0?[13578]|1[02])(\/)31)\1|(?:(?:0?[1,3-9]|1[0-2])(\/)(?:29|30)\2))(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$|^(?:0?2(\/)29\3(?:(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?(?:0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|(?:(?:16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))$|^(?:(?:0?[1-9])|(?:1[0-2]))(\/)(?:0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])\4(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$
```

To this form:

```
\^\(\?:\(\?:\(\?:0\?\[13578\]\|1\[02\]\)\(\\/\)31\)\1\|\(\?:\(\?:0\?\[1,3-9\]\|1\[0-2\]\)\(\\/\)\(\?:29\|30\)\2\)\)\(\?:\(\?:1\[6-9\]\|\[2-9\]\d\)\?\d{2}\)$\|\^\(\?:0\?2\(\\/\)29\3\(\?:\(\?:\(\?:1\[6-9\]\|\[2-9\]\d\)\?\(\?:0\[48\]\|\[2468\]\[048\]\|\[13579\]\[26\]\)\|\(\?:\(\?:16\|\[2468\]\[048\]\|\[3579\]\[26\]\)00\)\)\)\)$\|\^\(\?:\(\?:0\?\[1-9\]\)\|\(\?:1\[0-2\]\)\)\(\\/\)\(\?:0\?\[1-9\]\|1\d\|2\[0-8\]\)\4\(\?:\(\?:1\[6-9\]\|\[2-9\]\d\)\?\d{2}\)$
```

Now I no longer get invalid escaping errors in XML editors (using XML Spy), but I get this one:

```
invalid-escape: The given character escape is not recognized.
```

I have done the escape according to the XML schema specifications here:
https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#regexs Section F.1.1 there is an escape table.

Can anyone please help to nail this down right?

Thanks!

Comment: XSD regex does not know `^` and `$`, and I guess you need not escape `/`. Try `(?:(?:(?:(?:0?[13578]|1[02])(/)31)\1|(?:(?:0?[13-9]|1[0-2])(/)(?:29|30)\2))(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})|(?:0?2(/)29\3(?:(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?(?:0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|(?:(?:16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))|(?:(?:0?[1-9])|(?:1[0-2]))(/)(?:0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])\4(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2}))`

Comment: Not working, it gives me this error: unexpected-metaChar: The metacharacters ".", "\", "?", "*", "+", "{", "}", "(", ")", "|", "[" and "]" cannot occur unescaped at this position.

Comment: Please note that the escaped form I suggested in the original question, gave me a different error: invalid-escape: The given character escape is not recognized. which may suggest that I need to somehow define what is the escape character, somewhere.

Comment: I think backreferences are not allowed. If you only have 1 delimiter (`/`), try [`((((0?[13578]|1[02])/31)/|((0?[13-9]|1[0-2])/(29|30)/))((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})|(0?2/29/(((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?(0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|((16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))|(0?[1-9]|1[0-2])/(0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])/(1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})`](https://regex101.com/r/lF0dE4/1)

Comment: This seems to be accepted in XSD! But I have no way of testing it - I get error "Unescaped delimiter /" multiple times. What did you change to make it acceptable? And what do you mean by "backreferences are not allowed" ?

Comment: So, shall I post? What do you mean about *no way of testing it*? How are you testing it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110259/discussion-between-carmageddon-and-wiktor-stribizew).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check the XSD regex syntax [resources](http://www.xmlschemareference.com/regularExpression.html), you will notice that there is no support for [**non-capturing groups**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html#noncap) (`(?:...)`), nor [**backreferences**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html) (the `\n` like entities to refer to the text captured  with capturing groups, `(...)`).

Since the only delimiter is `/`, you can get rid of the backreference completely.

Use

```
((((0?[13578]|1[02])/31)/|((0?[13-9]|1[0-2])/(29|30)/))((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2}‌​)|(0?2/29/(((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?(0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|((16|[2468][048]|[35‌​79][26])00))))|(0?[1-9]|1[0-2])/(0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])/(1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lF0dE4/1)

Note that acc. to [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/xml.html):

> Particularly noteworthy is the complete absence of **anchors like the caret and dollar, word boundaries, and lookaround**. XML schema always implicitly anchors the entire regular expression. The regex must match the whole element for the element to be considered valid.

So, **you should not use `^` (start of string) and `$` (end of string) in XSD regex.**

The `/` symbol is escaped in regex flavors where it is a *regex delimiter*, and in XSD regex, there are no regex delimiters (as the only action is *matching*, and there are no modifiers: [*XML schemas do not provide a way to specify matching modes*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/xml.html)). So, **do not escape `/` in XSD regex**.

**TESTING AT ONLINE TESTERS NOTE**

If you test  at [regex101.com](http://regex101.com) or similar sites, note that in most cases you need to escape the `/` if it is selected as a regex delimiter. You can safely remove the `\` before `/` after you finished testing.

Answer (score 1):

OK, so you're starting from this (I'm going to insert newlines for readability):

```
    ^(?:(?:(?:0?[13578]|1[02])(\/)31)\1|(?:(?:0?[1,3-9]|1[0-2])(\/)
(?:29|30)\2))(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$
|^(?:0?2(\/)29\3(?:(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?(?:0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|(?:(?:16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))$|
^(?:(?:0?[1-9])|(?:1[0-2]))(\/)(?:0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])\4(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$
```

Horrendous stuff. Now, in XSD:

(a) there are no `^` and `$` anchors, they aren't needed (the pattern is implicitly anchored). So take them out. You've responded by escaping them as `\^` and `\$` but that doesn't make sense: you don't actually want circumflexes and dollar signs in your input.

(b) XSD doesn't recognize non-capturing groups `(?:xxxx)`. Just replace them with capturing groups - that is, remove the `?:` Again, you've escaped the question marks, which doesn't make any sense at all.

(c) The `\d` should probably be `[0-9]`, unless you actually want to match non-ASCII digits (e.g. Thai or Eastern Arabic digits)

(d) Slash (`/`) doesn't need to be escaped, and indeed can't be escaped. So replace `\/` with `/`.

(e) I see some back-references, `\1`, `\2`, `\4`. XSD regexes do not allow back-references. But as far as I can see, the back-references in this regex serve no useful purpose. Most of them seem to be back-references to a group of the form `(\/)` which can only match a single slash, so the back-reference `\1` can be simply replaced with `/`. Maybe they are throwbacks to some earlier form of the regex that allowed alternative delimiters but required them to be consistent.

From your attempts to fix the problems here, it seems to me that you don't have a very thorough understanding of regular expressions. I fear that to get this working, you are going to have to bite the bullet and learn how it works; debugging complex regular expressions is difficult, and you won't get it right by trial and error.