# XML Regex - Negative match

Tags: regex, xml, xsd

I have a problem with negative lookahead in XSD pattern.
When I specified:

```
<xs:pattern value="^(?!(00|\+\d))\d{6,}$"/>
```

then I got an error message:

```
Value '^(?!(00|\+\d))\d{6,}$' is not a valid XML regular expression.
```

Any idea why it does not work?

In online javascript validator it works fine (e.g. [here](https://regex101.com/r/jL5xW1/1) under unit tests section click on "run test").

I need to validate phone numbers. The phone number cannot include international prefixes (+\d) and (00).

Thanks

Comment: XSD [does not support](http://www.regular-expressions.info/xml.html) lookaround.

Comment: @horcrux  thanks, but it is not good for me :D

Comment: @horcrux, where can I find what is not supported in XSD pattern?

Comment: @peterko Aren't you satisfied with the answer below? If you need more details, ask the person who gave you an answer.

Comment: Note that in XSD, `\d` matches all Unicode digits, not just `[0-9]`

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36860613/how-to-properly-escape-regular-expression-pattern-in-xsd-schema/36862803#36862803)  is an SO question where some constructs not supported in XSD regex are described.

Comment: @peterko I linked you the reference in the first comment.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks a lot, your overview saved my time :)

Comment: I provided an answer below summarizing the main points and in a more concise way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following regex:

```
[1-9][0-9]{5,} | 0[1-9][0-9]{4,}
```

This matches a number which does *not* begin with zero and is followed by any digit (including zero) 5 or more times, and it also matches a number which starts with zero and is *not* immediately followed by zero, but after that can have 0-9.

Answer (score 0):

I will add my deleted comment as an answer:

```
([1-9][0-9]|[0-9][1-9])[0-9]{4,}
```

See [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hG8hT5/1).

The regex should work well for your scenario because

- `([1-9][0-9]|[0-9][1-9])` - matches either 1 digit from `1-9` ranges and any digit after or (`|`) any 1 digit followed with any digit but `0` - **making up 2 digits**
- `[0-9]{4,}` - matches 4 and more any digits.

This pattern only matches *a full/entire string* because all regex patterns inside XSD `pattern` are anchored by default (so, you do not have to and can't enclose the pattern with `^` and `$`).

Right, there is no lookaround support in XSD regex (no *lookaheads, nor lookbehinds*). Besides, **XSD regex has other interesting limitations/features**:

- `^` and `$` anchors
- Non-capturing groups like `(?:...)` (use capturing ones instead)
- `/` should not be escaped, do not use `\/`
- `\d` should be written as `[0-9]` to only match ASCII digits (same as in .NET)
- Back-references like `\1`, `\2` are not supported.
- No word boundaries are supported either.

See some [more XSD regex description at regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/xml.html).