# Not allowing a specific string in an XSD Regular expression

Tags: regex, xml, xsd

I'm trying to validate a restricted string using a regular expression ...

```
<xs:simpleType name="myStringType">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:pattern value="^urn:mystuff:v1:(ABC\.(?!Acme).\S+\.\S+\.a\d+\.v\d+|ABC\.Acme\.\S+\.a\d+\.\d+\.\d+)$"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

As you can see the regular expression I'm trying to use is

```
^urn:mystuff:v1:(ABC\.(?!Acme).\S+\.\S+\.a\d+\.v\d+|ABC\.Acme\.\S+\.a\d+\.\d+\.\d+)$
```

I would like the following to validate:

```
urn:mystuff:v1:ABC.Test.MyData.a1.v1
urn:mystuff:v1:ABC.Acme.MyData.a1.0.1
```

But I would like the following to fail

```
urn:mystuff:v1:ABC.Acme.MyData.a1.v1
```

This appears to work fine in an [online regex tester](https://regex101.com/r/dB1dF7/1) but when I use Oxygen XML Editor I get the following error.

```
 Pattern value '^urn:mystuff:v1:(ABC\.(?!Acme).\S+\.\S+\.a\d+\.v\d+|ABC\.Acme\.\S+\.a\d+\.\d+\.\d+)$' is not a valid regular expression. The reported error was: 'This expression is not supported in the current option setting.'.
```

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38436165/xml-regex-negative-match) suggests that lookaheads and lookbehinds are not supported in XSD regex but the question relates to number patterns so a brute force approach is taken in the example.  This is possible because there's a very limited subset of possibilities.

How does one deal with this when the values to be disallowed is a specific string?

Comment: To clear things up a bit, the dot in this sequence `(?!Acme).\S+`  is a literal or a metacharacter ? Or, is it a typo that shouldn't even be there ?

Comment: Literal. The examples so the pattern

Comment: @x15 did you delete your answer?

Comment: @x15 ah.  Thanks.  Went to go give it a try and poof.  Thanks for thinking about it

Comment: This one works...

Comment: Did you try this one out ?

Comment: @kjhughes this question has been revised to clarify and differentiate.  I also specifically noted how the referenced answer did not answer the question.  Clearly people agree and have something to add.  Please reopen.

Comment: @agf1997: Alright.  Reopened.   Sorry those didn't help.

Comment: **Related** (migrated from former close heading): (a) [XSD restriction that negates a matching string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9889206/290085)  (b) [XML schema restriction pattern for not allowing specific string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37563199/290085)  (c)  [XML Regex - Negative match](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38436165/290085)

Comment: This specific focused question with regex is extremely complex. I don't even like to think of it, although I have many times. And I consider myself an expert. This question happens to have a solution.

Comment: **_Note this word of caution ;_** It would be a stretch to assume that these assertion simulations are _covered ground_. I would consider each one a uniquely extraordinary question and answer !

Comment: Agree.  The other questions had useful tidbits but didn’t really provide a workable answer for this question as it has its own unique challenges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**adendum :**  Note that this solution plants an pseudo assertion at a fixed  location in the string.
For an example solution of an assertion that should span the entire string
see this question  [XML schema restriction pattern for not allowing specific string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37563199/xml-schema-restriction-pattern-for-not-allowing-specific-string)

---

**edit :**  As pointed out in a comment, use `(..)` instead of `(?:..)` if that is the only
supported construct.
Changed !

---

This series `(?!Acme)\S+\.` can be replaced with this large series :

`([^A]\S*|A([^c.]\S*)?|Ac([^m.]\S*)?|Acm([^e.]\S*)?)\.`

which is bigger but should cover all cases and makes the regex now :

```
urn:mystuff:v1:(ABC\.([^A]\S*|A([^c.]\S*)?|Ac([^m.]\S*)?|Acm([^e.]\S*)?)\.\S+\.a\d+\.v\d+|ABC\.Acme\.\S+\.a\d+\.\d+\.\d+)
```

https://regex101.com/r/qXv9HU/2

Expanded

```
 urn:mystuff:v1:
 (                             # (1 start)
      ABC \. 
      (                             # (2 start)
           [^A]  \S* 
        |  A 
           ( [^c.] \S* )?                # (3)
        |  Ac 
           ( [^m.] \S* )?                # (4)
        |  Acm  
           ( [^e.] \S* )?                # (5)
      )                             # (2 end)
      \. 
      \S+ \. a \d+ \. v \d+ 
   |  
      ABC \. Acme \. \S+ \. a \d+ \. \d+ \. \d+ 
 )                             # (1 end)
```

Comment: Unfortunately `(?: ... )` is also outside the XSD regex definition.

Answer (score 2):

XSD has a particular definition of what it accepts in regular expression, and it rather more restrictive than many other regular expression dialects. I think the intention of the designers was to use a "common subset" of popular regex dialects so that it could be easily implemented on any platform. You are using constructs like `(?! ... )` and `(?: ... )`that aren't defined in this subset. So is the answer from @x15, unfortunately.

Telling you why your attempt isn't working is easy, finding an alternative that does work is harder. I would go for the easy option which is to use an XSD 1.1 assertion like `test="matches($value, XX) or matches($value, YY) and not(matches($value, ZZ))"`. A solution using pure XSD 1.0 might be possible, but I can't immediately see it.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be to exploit this rule in [the XML Schem specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#rf-pattern):

> If multiple  element information items appear as children of a `<simpleType>`, the values should be combined as if they appeared in a single regular expression as separate branches.
>   Note:  It is a consequence of the schema representation constraint Multiple patterns (§4.3.4.3) and of the rules for restriction that pattern facets specified on the same step in a type derivation are ORed together, while pattern facets specified on different steps of a type derivation are ANDed together.

Instead of trying to match both allowed patterns with a single regex, specify two separate pattern facets. That would also extend more naturally if a third, fourth URN pattern is required.

Comment: That handles AND and OR, but it doesn't immediately provide a way of doing AND NOT.

Comment: On further reflection, I believe my suggested approach would work for the scenarios described in the question. The string `urn:mystuff:v1:ABC.Acme.MyData.a1.v1` will not match either of the regexes, so the 'AND NOT' is not required. Unless I'm missing something.

Comment: One of the 2 regex used an assertion `(?!Acme)` at a location and was in error via _unsupported_ construct. The NOT is needed because a specific item needs to be not.  Together all these conditions must all be true **(** `urn:mystuff:v1:ABC\.\S+\.\S+\.a\d+\.v\d+`  AND NOT `urn:mystuff:v1:ABC\.Acme\S*\.\S+\.a\d+\.v\d+` **)** OR **(** `urn:mystuff:v1:ABC\.Acme\.\S+\.a\d+\.\d+\.\d+` **)**